# Set methods to lua tables from C/C++/Rust

Tags: c, lua, rust, lua-table, lua-api

I want to set extra "methods" to some tables that are in some lua_State.

The state has the code like this:

```
obj = {}

function obj:method1()
    print("value from second method = " .. self.method2())
end
```

I load it by *do_file()* method. After this I want to add method2() to the table *obj*. This *method2()* must get on the stack the table *obj* (as *self*) to work properly.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
state.get_global("obj");
if state.is_table(-1) {
   state.push_string("method2");
   state.push_fn(Some(method2));
   state.set_table(-3);
}
```

or in C:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "obj");
if (lua_istable(L, -1)) {
    lua_pushstring(L, "method2");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, &lua_method2);
    lua_settable(L, -3);
}
```

The *method2()* function is written okay, same functions I use for "new_lib" and they work good.

When I do all that, in method2() I check:

```
if (lua_istable(L, -1)) {
    // Do some work
} else {
    print("not a table!");
}
```

And I get "not a table" instead of actual work.

How can I do such a thing? And will the method2() in Rust(C/C++, whatever) get *obj* table (*self*) as first parameter on a stack?

Comment: c/c++/rust/doesn't matter.... how can it not matter if you want a concrete answer?

Comment: Did you try that code? Did it work? If it didn't work *how* didn't it work? Did it explode?

Comment: @tobi303 Presumably this is a question about the Lua API, which is more or less the same regardless of what programming language you're using it from.

Comment: Edited the question, added more code and explanation. I hope I did it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table `T` and you call `T:Func()` and `T.Func` is any function, then `T` will be the first parameter in the method call.
So if in your code you call `obj:method2()` then `obj` will be the first parameter.

Note that you should call the function with the `:` operator like so `obj:method2()`. If you call it with `.` operator then you need to pass the obj table to the method or you run into the same nil error you have mentioned since there are no arguments passed in that case. The `:` operator is just a syntactic sugar for `obj.method2(obj)`.

I would also try use `lua_istable(L, 1)` since the arguments are at the bottom of the stack. If someone calls `obj:method2(2)` then the method would fail because top of the stack has a number value and not a table.
The stack is cleared for a function call so the arguments passed are always at the very bottom of the stack.

Btw. in the C code of yours you are missing the push for the function name.